# botocore.eventstream.EventStream returning response with very high latency

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I am using AWS S3 select with boto3 to get the chunk of CSV from the S3 bucket. The response returned by the query is an object of botocore.eventstream.EventStream.
After looping on the EventStream, the actual JSON response is decoded and loaded to Python list. The issue is that, looping over EventStream is taking around 4-5 minutes. Is there any way to speed it up?

The minimal code to achieve this is given below:

```
    query="""SELECT * FROM s3object s WHERE "s"."xyz"='"""+num+"""' AND "s"."datestr">='"""+date_raw+"""' AND "s"."timestr">='"""+time_raw+"""' AND "s"."datestr"<='""" +date_raw_to+"""' AND "s"."timestr"<='"""+time_raw_to+"""'"""
        
print("query: ", query)
key="base/"+filepath

t1=time.time()
resp = s3_client.select_object_content(
    Bucket=bucket_name,
    Key=key, # file name or complete path with folder
    Expression=query, # query to execute on the CSV
    ExpressionType='SQL',
    InputSerialization={
        "CSV": {
            'FileHeaderInfo': 'USE',
        },
    },
    OutputSerialization={
        'JSON': {}
    },
)
print("resp: ", resp)
print("resp: ", type(resp)) # prints <class 'dict'>

print(type(resp['Payload'])) # prints <class 'botocore.eventstream.EventStream'>

t2=time.time()
print("time taken to get select response: ", t2-t1) # 2.6 seconds
all_records=[]
t1=time.time()
for event in resp['Payload']: # loop over to get each record
    try:
        raw=event['Records']['Payload']
        s=str(raw)[1:]
        
        records = ast.literal_eval(str(event['Records']['Payload'])[1:])
        print("-----------------")
        all_records.append(records)
    except:
        pass
t2=time.time()
print("time taken to loop: ", t2-t1) # prints 300 seconds (too much)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!